# Are there some benchmark problems for CSP Solvers?

Tags: solver, constraint-programming, benchmark

I am building my own CSP solver with simple backtracking, AC3 filtering and variable/value ordering heuristics. It supports non binary constraints. I've done some good progress and I'd like to benchmark it.

Are there some benchmarks out there, like some standard/common CSP problems, or some problem data sets that researchers use for testing?

Ideally, I was hoping there is some standard file format of CSP problem definitions, like a csv or json or xml format, that I could import and parse with my solver. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 7):

Here's one: [CSPLib: A problem library for constraints](http://www.csplib.org/)

Answer (score 7):

The Minizinc constraint programming benchmark models are in Minzinc file format : https://github.com/MiniZinc/minizinc-benchmarks. Each year several CP solvers compete on some problems (see here : [Minizinc challenge](https://www.minizinc.org/challenge.html))